# How to ignore msg.delete() if not found discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```
execute(client, message) {
        message.channel.send(`Last heartbeat calculated ${ms(Date.now() - client.ws.shards.first().lastPingTimestamp, { long: true })} ago **${client.ws.ping}ms** ️`).then(msg => {
           setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), client.config.app.dtime) 
        });
```

Hi there, I was working on my discord bot and ran into a scenario like this, the code causing the problem is shown above. When this function runs, it sends the current ping of the bot to the message channel. and automatically deletes the msg after some time, but in case some person with admin privileges deletes the message manually. My bot will crash when it tries to delete so to avoid that how should I fix my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the promise rejection and void it as such:

```js
msg.delete().catch(() => null);
```

Even when the promise rejects, no errors will appear nor will the process crash

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your index file where you start the bot, and do this line

```
process.on("uncaughtException", (error) => {
        console.log(error)
})
```

It will console log an error, and won't crash, and also every time your bot is about to crash, it will just console it :)

Comment: Thank you, It works for now but now there will be an error code in the console log.
So alternative ideas are welcome. Trying to make a public bot so there will be tons of error code when it goes public.

Comment: Just do return ;), it will return, without any console errors :))), and also If I helped you, could you flag it as a good answer please? Im a newbie, it would help me much :)